# How to fetch data from WCF application to .aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am new in WCF application.
I have added a wcf Application in VS 2010. Now I add refence from http://www.btres.com/WL/TestWLDev/FlightServices.asmx this link. Now I want to fetch data to my .aspx page. Can any one guide me?

Folder "Service references",  includes FlightServices.wsdl , Reference.cs.

Comment: See [How to consume a web service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following links provide a variety of options and guidance for consuming a WCF Service from an ASP.NET web page.
http://www.csharptutorial.in/2012/08/cnet-how-to-consume-wcf-service-in.html#.Upx67cRDu_Y
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42643/Creating-and-Consuming-Your-First-WCF-Service
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb412167(v=vs.100).aspx

Regards,